# Not getting App_data folder in ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have created new empty web site `SQL_SERVER_PRACTICE_ONE` project in Visual Studio 2012.
But I am not getting `App_data` folder in Solution Explorer.

Comment: how to add App_data folder ?

Answer (score 4):

Right click the Project File. Then Select **Add** -> **Add ASP.Net Folder** -> **App_Data**